# why istio sidecar doen't support direct access by DNS

Tags: istio, istio-sidecar

I'm using istio 1.4.10 and trying to direct access External service by Dns.
Cause don't need traffic control and I Don't know service IP changed.

so.. Can i direct access by DNS.

Comment: This can be achieved by the recent, supported istio versoins. Your `1.4.10` version is not supported and doesn't get feature updates for a very long time. Please update to the latest version.

Comment: @Chris My company is ruuning on `1.4.10`, so I cann't update that.    
Did u give a link for `direct access DNS` ?    

There is other way to work this? like custom sidecar